# How to get full path for any (including local) function in python?

Tags: python, function, reflection, inspect

`f"{f.__module__}.{f.__name__}"` doesn't work because function `f` can be local, eg inside another function. We need to add some kind of marked (`.<local>.`) in the path to specify that this function is local. But how to determine when we need to add this marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f.__qualname__` instead of `__name__`.